# Find where I can place 4 queens in 4*4 chessboard?

Tags: algorithm

I am not asking for the solution. I want all the possible placements.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Is this a homework question?  What language, or is this language-agnostic?  Please bit a bit more specific.

Comment: Seriously you can find them quickly by hand! There are only `4! = 24` permutations.

Comment: If you're not asking for the solution, what are you asking for?

Comment: Perhaps you should also specify the _rules_ of this search. You can place 4 queens anywhere on a chess board fine. (if there are none, leaving out "queens" and "chess" might've been clearer, just calling it a grid of bits)

Comment: @Petar: Wrong. There are 1820 solutions for this one (assuming I understand him)

Comment: What's the difference between "the solution" and "all the possible placements"?

Comment: And out of the 24 permutations, there are only 2 ways to do it, and they are a mirror image of each other.

Comment: @Programmer - I consider the queens must not attack each other.

Comment: @Petar: Oh! Sorry. I thought the person is asking of all possible placements irrespective of the fact that they can attack. Assuming queens identical, only 2 ways. How did you get 24? Arent queens identical in such optimization problems

Comment: @Mark Byers: I think he wanted to know what the possible placements are so that he can check his program's output for correctness?

Comment: @Programmer - 24 is a sample upper limit of the configurations to verify, not the number of solutions.

Comment: This question is so ambiguous. I wonder if he meant something else by 4*4. May be he was talking about a chessboard with 16 rows :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is in C#. Hope it helps

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new Program();
        StreamWriter saveText = new StreamWriter("Output.txt",true);
        obj.fourQueen(0, 0, 4, "");
        Console.Read();

    }


    public void fourQueen(int r , int c, int queensLeft, string onePlacement){
        if(queensLeft == 0){
            //onePlacement may not be a answer
            Console.WriteLine(onePlacement);
        return ;

        }

        if(c==4){
            //If I have reached the end of 1 row, go to next one
            c=0;
            r=r+1;
        }
        if(r==4){
            //I have considered all rows and still not put all queens. cannot be a solution
            return;
        }
        int te = queensLeft - 1;






        int newcol = c + 1;
        fourQueen(r,newcol,te,onePlacement+"| ("+r+","+c+")|");
        //Note: As i am placing queen in (r,c) above, there is no point in continuing //recursive call from r,c+1 as cannot place another in same row. I should
        //go from  r+1,0
        fourQueen(r,newcol,queensLeft,onePlacement);


    }
}
```

}

Comment: The above code given you all possible placments irrespective of the fact if they attack or not

Comment: thanks. This is exactly what i wanted. the comment about 1820 is also helpful.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to place four queens on a 4x4 chessboard such that none of the queens attack any of the others:

```
_ ♕ _ _    _ _ ♕ _
_ _ _ ♕    ♕ _ _ _
♕ _ _ _    _ _ _ ♕
_ _ ♕ _    _ ♕ _ _
```

[Source](http://jsomers.com/nqueen_demo/nqueens.html)

**Algorithm**

I'm not going to give you the code but I can show you how the algorithm should work. To find the solutions you can use a brute force algorithm with backtracking.

- For each row try placing a queen in the first free squre in that row, then move to the next row.
- If there are no available squares at least one queen is in the wrong place.
- Go back to the previous row and move the queen the the next available square.
- Repeat until a solution is found.

Here's how the algorithm works for a 4x4 board:

```
♕ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
```

The second row's queen cannot go in the first or second column because they are both attacked, so try the third:

```
♕ _ _ _
_ _ ♕ _
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
```

Now the third row.... no spaces are available. Backtrack and try a new position for the second row.

```
♕ _ _ _
_ _ _ ♕
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
```

Now we can place the third row queen:

```
♕ _ _ _
_ _ _ ♕
_ ♕ _ _
_ _ _ _
```

No luck on the fourth row. And we already tried every position for the third row, and for the second, so backtrack to the first row:

```
_ ♕ _ _
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
```

etc...

Good luck!